# Why exactly is it bad to whitelist all domains with Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

So I have created a small android app for a band just to show their music, upcoming shows... but I use a lot of outside resources so I use the the Cordova whitelist plugin to allow me to get my resources. I have read multiple times now that you should not use `<allow-navigation href="*" />` because of many security reasons and it should only be used while testing but I can not find an example as to why exactly. Google has not helped me yet with this question so is there really any harm in publishing my app with the above line of code to allow access to all sites? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for preventing the app loading untrusted pages, if you check cordova's security guide, any script that loads can access directly the cordova scripts.

Basically, someone could compromise one of the pages you are loading to load a script on other domain that somehow takes advantage of the cordova scripts for whatever the attacker wants. By whitelisting you are preventing cordova to load those scripts (only load from the sources the app should trust).

[security guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/security/index.html)

Comment: This github repo has some really good best practices and explains in detail how the whitelist works: https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-matrix.md